# How to set edit text with different text on image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here I want to set `Text` widget with different functionality such as change font family, font size, font color, deleting font and add font. This all of the functionality I want to handle dynamically.

So, how I can I add this functionality in flutter?

[image]